# Using get() with a list

Tags: r

Is there a way to use `get()` with a list object?

The functionality I'm looking for is akin to:

```
x <- list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9))
get(paste("x$a",sep=""))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
get("a", envir=list2env(x))
```

But that is more or less as useful as `x[['a']]`. It seems you might also be looking for the eval/parse route:

```
eval(parse(text="x$a"))
```

Comment: New to me too.  But is it needed here? Joshua uses `get` without it in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `pos=` argument:

```
> get("a",x)
[1] 1 2 3
```

In order for your example to work, you would need to evaluate the expression, since `"x$a"` isn't a valid name.

```
> eval(parse(text=paste("x$a",sep="")))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: +1 Probably worth mentioning that several R Guru's aren't very kind when it comes to the `parse(...)` idiom. If one is considering such an idiom, they might like to avail themselves of `if(!require(fortunes)) { install.packages("fortunes") }; fortune(106)`

Comment: @Gavin: agreed.  I wouldn't recommend the eval/parse route.  It was just for illustration.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to sound critical. I understood the intention behind you showing the second example. I just wanted to add a rider. Should have made that clearer.

Comment: @Gavin: I didn't think you were being critical.  I just wanted to clarify that I don't recommend that approach even though I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this alternative would work for you?

```
get("x")[["a"]]
```